# exporting specific yahoo financials online table to csv with python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv, pandas-datareader

I am writing here because I am wondering if there is an existing module or a fairely easy way that would permit me to take an online table from yahoo finance/financials (such as this one: https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/MMM/financials?p=MMM&.tsrc=fin-srch), instead of me trying to make the `csv module` write everything manually to form a data-frame.

It has been very tedious so far and as I am new to programming I am sure I could make my life easier some way. I am aware of `pandas` and `pandas.DataReader`, but I am not interested by the trading history and the data varies from one company to an other therefore the tables are filled with various amount of data.

I am trying to get the income statement, balance sheet as well as the cash-flow tables in order to make further calculations once I have the data locally.

Looking forward to hear your suggestions,

Thank you very much!

Comment: I haven't used this module, but you can find it at [Yahoo! Finance market data downloader](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance).

    # show financials
    msft.financials
    msft.quarterly_financials

This, I thought, would confirm it.

Comment: You should take a look at [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery).

Comment: I tried the yahoo finance downloader but it seems there is a problem as it returns empty dataframes most of the time. But yahooquery works wonders. Thank you very much for both your answers!